# How to check data in different rows in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently getting data from database, then if i checked the checkbox more than 2 rows, it will sum up the total of SENDQTY and send the details from GridView3 to GridView4. Now how can i check if the STOCKCODE from the 2 rows is different, it will prompt error message?

```
protected void showGridView()
{
    int match = 0;
    int total = 0;
          
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[9] { new DataColumn("DODetailID"), new DataColumn("SALESORDERNO"), new DataColumn("STOCKCODE"), new DataColumn("SENDQTY"), new DataColumn("scanflag"), new DataColumn("REJECT"), new DataColumn("DispatchOrderID"), new DataColumn("DispatchDATE"), new DataColumn("DELORDERNO") });
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView3.Rows)
    {
         if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
         {
              CheckBox CheckBox1 = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox);

              //int qty = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[4].Text);
              if (CheckBox1.Checked)
              {
                  string DODetailID = (row.Cells[1].FindControl("DODetailID") as Label).Text;
                  string SALESORDERNO = (row.Cells[2].FindControl("SALESORDERNO") as Label).Text;
                  string STOCKCODE = (row.Cells[3].FindControl("STOCKCODE") as Label).Text;                 
                  int SENDQTY = Convert.ToInt32((row.Cells[4].FindControl("SENDQTY") as Label).Text);
                  CheckBox scanflag = (row.Cells[5].FindControl("scanflag") as CheckBox);
                  string REJECT = (row.Cells[6].FindControl("REJECT") as Label).Text;
                  string DispatchOrderID = (row.Cells[7].FindControl("DispatchOrderID") as Label).Text;
                  string DispatchDATE = (row.Cells[8].FindControl("DispatchDATE") as Label).Text;
                  string DELORDERNO = (row.Cells[9].FindControl("DELORDERNO") as Label).Text;
                  Session["STOCKCODE"] = STOCKCODE.ToString();
                       
                  dt.Rows.Add(DODetailID, SALESORDERNO, STOCKCODE, SENDQTY, scanflag, REJECT, DispatchOrderID, DispatchDATE, DELORDERNO);
                  match++;
                       
                  total = total + SENDQTY;
                  GridView4.DataSource = dt;
                  GridView4.DataBind();  
             }                   
         }
     }       
 }

protected void btnContinue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
     showGridView();
     mp3.Show(); // this is showing GridView4
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to run two for each loops. Run the for/each loop on the data first time in which you count check boxes (and stock code). You can then in code decide to run/use your existing loop.

```
Collection MyCheckList = New Collection;
Boolean ListBad = false;
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView3.Rows)
{
     if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     {
          CheckBox CheckBox1 = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox);
          Label txtStock = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("STOCKCODE") as Label);
         if CheckBox.Checked {
            if MyCheckList.Contains(txtStock.Text) {
               ListBad = true;
               Exit for;
            else
               ListBad.Add(txtSTock)
            }
```

etc. etc. etc

etc. etc.

In other words, run a test/loop over the data - put the stockcode into a collection if checked, and if such a stockcode already exists, then you know more then 1 checked of a given stock exists, and thus your flag ListBad = true when you finish  that loop process.

You could also add the collection idea to your existing loop. And upon exit, you know if more then one stockcode was checked. So you probably don't need a separate first loop, but you do have to "build up" a list of checked + stockcodes if you checking for an already existing stock code. So build up a checked list in that collection and thus you know if a stockcode been used + checked in that list more then once.